# Detecting TLD for localization

Tags: iis, redirect, cname-record, tld, localization

I have many TLD's for my domain, for US users it's .COM, for German users it's .DE, etc. I redirect them all to the .COM domain using CNAME records. The reason is to prevent getting a penalty from Google for duplicate content.

Is there a way to still detect the TLD the user entered, so I can display the page in the right language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CNAME records, google will still regard the sites as different domains, and will penalize them for duplicate content.

You should redirect your users with a HTTP 301 response. When you do this, you can also add a query string when redirecting:

```
www.example.de -> www.example.com/?lang=de
```

This way, you won't be penalized for duplicate content, **and** you can detect your user's language.